# Gnuplot get value of a particular data in a datafile? (with or without using stats)

Tags: gnuplot

Imagine I have a data file with two column. In `gnuplot` running

```
stats 'datafile' u 1:2
```

allows me find the minimum and maximum for the two columns. The variable
`STATS_index_min_x` and `STATS_index_min_y` give respectively the index of the
minimum for the first and second column. It says in the documentation that they
are such that

```
data[STATS_index_min_x] == STATS_min_x
```

Now imagine that need to have access to `data[STATS_index_min_x-1]` or
`data[STATS_index_min_x+1]`. How can I do that ? Actually how can I access any
particular data of any column in `gnuplot`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot access the data in your file in this way (i.e. like an array).

On Linux/cygwin, you could work with an helper function that extracts the value directly from the underlying datafile using `awk`. You can define the following function:

```
getValue(row,col,filename) = system('awk ''{if (NR == '.row.') print $'.col.'}'' '.filename.'')
```

If your datafile is called `datafile` and contains these values:

```
1  1.4
2  4.3
3  2.5
4  0.0
5  9.0
```

Which gives:

```
gnuplot> print getValue(3,1,"datafile")
3
gnuplot> print getValue(1,2,"datafile")
1.4
```

Comment: How the code above would differ if one needs to store the value in a variable for later use? i.e. c = getValue(3,1,"datafile") instead of print getValue(3,1,"datafile")? Thank you

Comment: Apparently adding real() in front of system helps!

Answer (score 3):

`Gnuplot` hadn't been designed for this, but you can cheat a little bit ;-)

```
stats 'datafile' u 1:2
plot[STATS_index_max_x+1:STATS_index_max_x+1.5] 'datafile.dat' u 0:1
```

then `GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN` (and `GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX`) contains the value you wanted.

---

**NOTE**

```
plot '<datafile>' u 0:<column>
```

plots the desidered column versus 0,1,2...

Answer (score 3):

You could use `stats` combined with `every` to select the data.  The following should print the values you are looking for:

```
stats 'datafile' u 1
imin = STATS_index_min
stats 'datafile' u 1 every ::(imin-1)::(imin-1)
print STATS_min
stats 'datafile' u 1 every ::(imin+1)::(imin+1)
print STATS_min
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out the line number for which column 5 in the input datafile has its maximum value:

```
stats 'thermal_site_1.dat' u 5
```

Load into the variable `Tc` the corresponding value of column 1 in the same datafile, via a 'fake' plotting command and an if conditional:

```
plot 'thermal_site_1.dat' u ($0==STATS_index_max ? Tc=$1 : NaN):5
```

You can see the desired value via:

```
print Tc
```